# Chrome: page loading is slow until DevTools(F12) shows

Tags: google-chrome

My env: **Chrome 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) on windows 10**

When I open a link in a new page, the page loading is  very slow. I can see the loading icon is running but the page keeps blank for a long time(10 seconds or more).

But when I press F12 to show the DevTools window, the page content loads immediately.

So what is the problem, and how to fix it? Many thanks

Comment: same for me, anyone could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, finally I realised that it was activated **Throttling** under the **Network** tab, and it was selected "Slow 3G" mode,  don't know how it has been activated. As you can see there is an alert icon with the Network tab name

[image]